# Spring MVC - how to correctly assign userProfiles to a single user?

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

So far, in my application, I have a single master user. But when I try to display it on my view layer, it gets multiplied by the number of roles it has.

My User entity definition is:

```
public class User {

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="sso_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private String ssoId;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="password", nullable=false)
private String password;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="first_name", nullable=false)
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="last_name", nullable=false)
private String lastName;

@Column(name="email", nullable=false)
private String email;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="state", nullable=false)
private String state=State.ACTIVE.getState();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_user_profile", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName="id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_profile", referencedColumnName="id") })
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();

// getters and setters
```

The UserProfile entity is defined as:

```
public class UserProfile {

@Column(name="type", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
private String type = UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType();

// getters and setters
```

The UserProfileType enum is defined as:

```
public enum UserProfileType {

USER("USER"),
DBA("DBA"),
ADMIN("ADMIN");

String type;

private UserProfileType(String userProfileType) {
    this.type = userProfileType;
}

public String getUserProfileType() {
    return type;
}
```

On my database, the table user has only one entry (for the master user), the table user_profile has 3 entries (ADMIN, USER and DBA) and the table user_user_profile, which links both, has 3 entries, like:

```
 id_user(master) id_profile(admin)
 id_user(master) id_profile(dba)
 id_user(master) id_profile(user)
```

I do believe the problem lies on the User entity, more precisely on the following excerpt:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_user_profile", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName="id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_profile", referencedColumnName="id") })
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
```

But I can't see what's wrong here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by including the following annotation to where I thought was the problem:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinTable(name = "hrm_user_user_profile", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName="id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_profile", referencedColumnName="id") })
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles;
```

Now it's working as should.